# Geometric Interpretation of the Neyman-Pearson lemma

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Consider the test problem
$$
H_0: \vartheta=\vartheta_0 \quad \text{versus} \quad H_1: \vartheta = \vartheta_1
$$
where $f_{\vartheta_0}: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow [0,1] $ and $f_{\vartheta_1}: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow [0,1] $ are two probability densities between which we want to choose.

Let
$$
\Psi := \left\{ \psi: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow [0,1] \; \text{ is a test}\right\}
$$
and
$$
S := \left\{ \left(\mathbb{E}_{\vartheta_0}\psi, \mathbb{E}_{\vartheta_0}\psi \right): \psi \in \Psi \right\} \subset [0,1]^2
$$

Which points in $S$ correspond with

- tests with significance level $\alpha \in (0, 1)$?
- the uniformly most powerful tests of significance level $\alpha \in (0, 1)$?

**Remark:** I am a bit lost here because I do not know if for e.g. there is a test for each sensitivity for a given significance.

Comment: Are you missing a $\vartheta_1$ in your definition of $S$?